# angular ui.grid search by field

Tags: angular-ui-grid

If I turn off enableFilter and roll my own input fields to search through the grid, how do I search only by one column?

See my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5V5nj7Nt1Fp7nFG2HVE9?p=preview)

```
    $scope.searchGrid = function(searchTerm){
    console.log("Term: " + searchTerm);
    $scope.gridOptions.data = $filter('filter')(myData, searchTerm, undefined);
  }
```

I want to have multiple input fields and send in the filter to each column as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You would typically bind to a specific `gridApi.grid.columns[x].filters[0].term`, that's basically what the grid implementation of the filters does.

You'd end up with something like this:
http://plnkr.co/edit/2u56wGFUOCxPLp4ekEkT?p=preview

The other problem is that you now have filter boxes, which presumably you didn't want.  You can suppress these by playing with the headerTemplates, but it is a bit of messing around.